# Do these kinds of matrices qualify as circulant matrices?

Tags: matrices, finite-groups, markov-chains, circulant-matrices

In the Wikipedia article on [circulant matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix), circulant matrices are given as follows:

\begin{equation}
C=
\begin{bmatrix}
c_0     & c_{n-1} & \dots  & c_{2} & c_{1}  \\
c_{1} & c_0    & c_{n-1} &         & c_{2}  \\
\vdots  & c_{1}& c_0    & \ddots  & \vdots   \\
c_{n-2}  &        & \ddots & \ddots  & c_{n-1}   \\
c_{n-1}  & c_{n-2} & \dots  & c_{1} & c_0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Now, in the following finite state machine, an interesting matrix comes up. Imagine we have a binary array of fixed width, say, 3, and we number the possible states of that array from 0-7. Each time we want to advance state, we drop the left-most digit from the array and push either a zero or one onto the right, forming a new 3-digit binary number. So each state has only two possible destination states based on this evolution.

The adjacency matrix for such a state machine looks like this (zeros omitted):

\begin{equation}
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 1 &&&&&& \\
&& 1 & 1 &&&& \\
&&&& 1 & 1 && \\
&&&&&& 1 & 1  \\
 1 & 1 &&&&&& \\
&& 1 & 1 &&&& \\
&&&& 1 & 1 && \\
&&&&&& 1 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Do people call this a "block circulant matrix" or something? Is there any literature? I think the "width" of the rotated block corresponds to the arity of the field (so for ternary digits the width would be 3 instead of 2), and the matrix dimensions would be $3^3 = 27$ instead of $2^3 = 8$.

Comment: Yes, "block-circulant" is an appropriate naming.